# Installing module "Configobj 4.7.2" error

Tags: python, import, module, installation, traceback

I was trying to install the module ConfigObj. I did everything correctly

Typed in CMD:

> **python setup.py install**

But tells me a traceback (error)

```
> C:\Users\Frederik\Desktop\configobj-4.7.2>python setup.py install
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "setup.py", line 13, in
> <module>
>     from configobj import __version__ as VERSION   File "C:\Users\Frederik\Desktop\configobj-4.7.2\configobj.py", line 1644
>     except Exception, e:
>                     ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> 
> C:\Users\Frederik\Desktop\configobj-4.7.2>
```

Can everyone tell me how to fix this, there shouldn't be an error in the configobj.py i've installed it before on a another computer.

Downloaded the module from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/configobj

My operating system is Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

configObj is for python 2 only.

I should elaborate.

the module you are trying to install is using a syntax that was dropped in python 3. it is available in python 2 up to 2.7.5 (current).  As the error is showing perfectly valid python 2 as a syntax error, one must conclude that you are using python 3, and the module does not support python 3.  Also, the Pypi link only lists python 2 versions in its categories.

Downgrade your python, or port the module to python 3

Comment: Do you know how to port things a link to a tutorial or anything else?

Comment: @Frederik http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/pyporting.html is the official guide, though it assumes you are well versed in the differences between the 2 languages (they are, when considering compatibility, different languages, even though they look and feel the same).  you could always try running `2to3` on it, and see where that gets you.  That will take care of all the obvious things, and give you warnings about things it cant automatically fix.  Beyond that, its a lot of hard work.